# Open source lightweight modern CI/CD system with ability to display build errors/warnings in its web GUI

Tags: open-source, .net, asp.net, continuous-integration

I've used CruiseControl.Net as a CI/CD for my older projects, and you could configure it to show the build errors and warnings in a separate, pretty and easily to read web interface. That was amazing. Unfortunately, CruiseControl.Net is long time abandoned. Not modern at all.

I briefly used TeamCity which also had (and I think still have) a similar feature for .NET projects. Yet, it is commercial, not opensource, and I want a full on-prem and opensource solution.

There's Jenkins, which as I recall also have this feature. But Jenkins is a resource-hungry monster, requiring Java, comsuming a lot of resources even when idling (the project is pretty small, so every bit of resource is important) etc. A bit of overkill, and not lightweight.

All the other CI/CDs I encountered provide only a build log display and... That's all. No UI for errors and/or warnings encountered during build, you got to dig into the build log manually.

The project in question is a .NET 6.0 ASP .NET Core project.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [drone](https://www.drone.io/)? It's Docker-based and has GUI options such as https://github.com/drone/drone-ui